# SQL - Create a formatted ouput with placeholder rows

Tags: sql

For reasons of our IT department, I am stuck doing this entirely within an SQL query.

Simplified, I have this as an input table:

[image: input table]

And I need to create this:

[image: output table]

And I am just not sure where to start with this.  In my normal C# way of thinking its easy.  Column1 is ordered, if the value in Col1 is new, then add a new row to the output and put the contents in column1 in the output.  Then, whilst the contents of the input Column1 is unchanged, keep adding the contents of column2 to new rows.

In SQL... nope, I just cannot see the right way to start!

Comment: That's a presentation issue and should be handled in the application. Relations don't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a presentation issue that can be easily done in the application or presentation layer. In SQL this can be clunky. The goal of a database is not to render a UI but to store and retrieve data fast and also efficiently, in order to serve as many clients as possible with the same hardware and software resources constraints.

The query that could do this can look like:

```
with
y as (
  select col1, row_number() over(order by col1) as r1
  from (select distinct col1 as col1 from t) x
),
z as (
  select
    t.col1, y.r1, t.col2,
    row_number() over(partition by t.col1 order by t.col2) as r2
  from t
  join y on y.col1 = x.col1
)
select col1, col2
from (
  select col1, null as col2, r1, 0 from y
  union all
  select null, col2, r1, r2 from z
) w
order by r1, r2
```

As you see, it looks clunky and bloated.

Answer (score 0):

You need a header row for each group which will consist of `col1` and `null` and all the rows of the table with `null` as `col1`.
You can do it with `UNION ALL` and conditional sorting:

```
select 
  case when t.col2 is null then t.col1 end col1, 
  t.col2
from (
  select col1, col2 from tablename
  union all
  select distinct col1, null from tablename   
) t 
order by 
  t.col1, 
  case when t.col2 is null then 1 else 2 end, 
  t.col2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rLKt9s2nMSt1WY9Fg3kTSZ/0) (for MySql but it is standard SQL).
Results:

```
| col1 | col2  |
| ---- | ----- |
| SetA |       |
|      | BH101 |
|      | BH102 |
|      | BH103 |
| SetB |       |
|      | BH201 |
|      | BH202 |
|      | BH203 |
```

Comment: Many thanks, this is the solution I went for in the end.  I am well aware that I shouldn't be using SQL in this way, but.., needs must.

Comment: @Etalon fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, formatting should be done outside of SQL, but if you have no choice, here is some SQL Server code that will generate your output

```
select * 
 from (
 select top 100 
     case 
     when col2 is null then ' '+col1
     else '' end as firstCol,
     IsNull(col2,'') as Col2
     from dbo.test t1 
     group by col1,col2 with rollup
     order by col1,col2

 ) x 
 where x.firstcol is not  null
```